# InvalidSelectorException while trying to identify web element in robot framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

> ign-In                                                               | FAIL |
>   InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector xpath=`//*[@id='user_email']` is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
>   InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression xpath=`//*[@id='user_email']` because of the following error:
>   TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_ (file:///var/folders/5f/6mvs5x1j37s5q3_38kjfwkgr0000gn/T/tmp1Nrpuj/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10633)
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementsInternal_ (file:///var/folders/5f/6mvs5x1j37s5q3_38kjfwkgr0000gn/T/tmp1Nrpuj/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10691)
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElements (file:///var/folders/5f/6mvs5x1j37s5q3_38kjfwkgr0000gn/T/tmp1Nrpuj/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10695)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/5f/6mvs5x1j37s5q3_38kjfwkgr0000gn/T/tmp1Nrpuj/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/5f/6mvs5x1j37s5q3_38kjfwkgr0000gn/T/tmp1Nrpuj/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/5f/6mvs5x1j37s5q3_38kjfwkgr0000gn/T/tmp1Nrpuj/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)

Comment: his is the HTML code :
<input id="user_email" class="emailCorrect email required required_field " type="email" value="" title1="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address" name="user[email]" email="true" data-toggle="tooltip"/>

Comment: Is it possible that your input field is in an iframe?

Comment: Since the XPath is valid I believe you have hit a bug in the Firefox webdriver. I used to get this occasionally in IE. Is this consistently reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the error message explained why :

> The given selector xpath=`//*[@id='user_email']` is either invalid or does not result in a `WebElement`.

In this case, `//*[@id='user_email']` is valid XPath expression, so it must be no element matched by that XPath. That's all I can tell from the information provided.

Comment: Nooooo. Don't post HTML in comment. Edit your question with the HTML and format it properly